# Rails 6 - Should I put my CSS & JS in rails asset pipeline or webpacker or through Amazon Cloudfront? Which is the most efficient?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack

I use to host my CSS files in the rails asset pipeline and JS on webpacker. I recently realize my webpage has been loading slower and slower.

I ran Chrome lighthouse on my site and found that my CSS and JS assets are "render-blocking resources" and causing my page to load slower.

I've already tried moving all of my CSS and JS over to webpacker (semantic-ui css is still being imported by the rails asset pipeline, had lots of problems trying to make this work but couldnt still)

I notice on Chrome lighthouse that my load time improved marginally, I guess its from the minification of CSS and JS by webpacker but it's no where near the improvements I was looking for.

So my question here is, what is the most efficient method to serve CSS and JS files for rails app?

My app is hosted on Heroku's Hobby Tier.. could this be a factor as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both approaches should allow you to achieve similar results. I don't know rails asset pipeline, but if it's used similarly to webpack it just changes your files on the build time & it's up to you how much code the user gets to download.

First of all, you can check the output size - in webpack, you can check the build standard output, or directly check the files it creates.

One trap you could be failing into with webpack is to have it set up wrongly. It could anything, from not minimizing code when for production build to having loades set up in a way that makes your images included directly inside js as data URL.

One advantage of using webpack, is that allows you to set up more complicated loading logic - for example lazy loading. Here something more about lazy load:
https://dev.to/marcinwosinek/lazy-load-library-in-application-build-with-webpack-5757

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!